# eBay API motors site - search by attributes

Tags: ebay-api

I was wondering if anyone knows if there is an option in the eBay API to search the motors category by attributes.

I.E. Search by Vehicle Year - Make - Model?

Basically I want to be able to search the motors site using the year, make and model method.

I have read through the documentation here:

http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/callref/finditemsbycategory.html

And I could not find any way to search based on those attributes.  I hope someone here can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have found the solution deeper into the API documentation.  To accomplish what I need to do I need to use the findItemsAdvanced call as so:

```
http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?
    OPERATION-NAME=findItemsAdvanced&
    SERVICE-VERSION=1.11.0&
    SECURITY-APPNAME=YourAppID&
    RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML&
    REST-PAYLOAD&
    paginationInput.entriesPerPage=2&
    keywords=1999%20chevrolet%20camaro&
    categoryId=40018
```

The keyword will search the Item Compatibility option in the search results so for the keyword all you need to use is the year make and model.

Answer (score 2):

You can search specifically by make, model, and years without using keywords. The eBay documentation is a little bit difficult to understand, but any of the parameters they search by on the actual site you search by using [aspect filters](https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/findItemsAdvanced.html#Request.aspectFilter). For instance, if you wanted to search for every Honda Civic between 1994 and 2001, it would look something like this:

```
http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?
OPERATION-NAME=findItemsAdvanced&
SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&
SECURITY-APPNAME=YourAppID&
RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON&
REST-PAYLOAD&
paginationInput.pageNumber=1&
paginationInput.entriesPerPage=100&
categoryId=6001&
keywords=&
outputSelector=AspectHistogram&
aspectFilter(0).aspectName=Make&
aspectFilter(0).aspectValueName=Honda&
aspectFilter(1).aspectName=Model&
aspectFilter(1).aspectValueName=Civic&
aspectFilter(2).aspectName=Model+Year&
aspectFilter(2).aspectValueName=1998%7C1999%7C2000%7C2001
```

Comment: Indeed. This will do what is expected (search the aspect/attribute metadata) where the keyword search (Jeff's own answer) will search for the specified keyword text, which potentially will give a different result (the keyword string could exist somewhere other than in the intended attribute/aspect). Thanks, CourtDemone, your example showed me where I was going wrong: I was labelling the fields "name" and "valueName" (and many permutations thereof) rather than "aspectName" and "aspectValueName" and eBay kept silently eating them. Sigh.